# Libgdx: more efficient way of using Vector 3?

Tags: java, libgdx, game-design, optimization

I currently use

```
if(cam.frustum.pointInFrustum(new Vector3((float)posX, (float)posY, 0)))
```

To check if my sprite is in the camera's view. I have to make a new Vector3 every frame wich is very inefficient.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you have efficiency issues? Did you use a profiler on your game and realized that this particular line was inefficient? What I'm trying to do now is see if you're doing premature optimization.

Comment: "Which is very inefficient" — not necessarily. [There's a decent chance that your virtual machine will be able to handle short-lived objects like these without breaking a sweat, in some cases even just using temporary registers rather than doing any allocation at all.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09275/index.html) As Alexandre Vaillancourt says, make sure you've profiled to determine whether this bit of code is really causing a problem, and that it's severe enough to be worth adding complexity to change it. "`new` is bad" is just a rule of thumb, not a law of physics.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the allocation of the `Vector3` you're worried about you might consider keeping an instance as a private member of the class and re-use that;

```
private final Vector3 v3 = new Vector3();

public void yourMethod() {
  if(cam.frustum.pointInFrustum(v3.set((float)posX, (float)posY, 0))) {
  }
}
```

Another way, if you have many of these instances you could apply pooling;

```
private final Pool<Vector3> pool = new Pool();

public void yourMethod() {
  Vector3 v3 = pool.obtain();
  if(cam.frustum.pointInFrustum(v3.set((float)posX, (float)posY, 0))) {
  }
  pool.free(v3);
}
```